# trying to get data from two requests

Tags: mysql, node.js

I try to get data from two requests on two table. But I've some difficulties to get back them as I expect. I've some group andfor each group I want to get the list of all element included in this group. So I want all groups id and all items related to them.

So I execute the second query into the callback of the first into a loop to execute the query as many time as I've results from the first query. I think thant my problem come from the loop

```
Groupe.getGroupeAndEqs = function getGroupeAndEqs(result) {
  sql.query("SELECT DISTINCT idGrp FROM groupe_equipement", function (err, res){
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(err, null);
    }
    else {
      for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
        sql.query("SELECT e.nom FROM equipement as e, groupe_equipement as g where g.idGrp=? AND e.id = g.idEq", res[i].idGrp, function(err, res2){
          if(err){
            console.log("error: ", err);
            result(err, null);
          }
          else{
           // result(null, res);
           //I try to create an attribute with the result of the second query
           res[i].equipements += res2;
           //console.log(res[i]);
           //resu += result(null, res);
          console.log(res2);
          }
        });
      }
   result(null, res);
    }
  });
}
```

I only get the result of the first query

Comment: Is `result` a function elsewhere in your code? If so, it looks like you are passing it the `res`, which would be the result of the first query. If you want to pass it a modified version of `res`, then you might want to create a variable and pass that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the whole thing in a single query. That may half your total process time. Check this query.

```
select g.idGrp, group_concat(distinct e.nom) from equipement e
inner join groupe_equipement g
on e.id = g.idEq
group by g.idGrp
```